# Remover espaço em branco do chart

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net

Estou enfrentando um problema que não consigo solucionar.
Tenho uma página, e nela tem 2 *charts*, mas o problema, é que esses *charts*, ficam pequenos, com muito espaço em branco em volta deles.
Já tentei configurar a propriedade `Position` e `InnerPlotPosition`, mas piora, pois fica um quadro branco por cima do gráfico.

Hoje os fontes que tenho estão da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <asp:Chart ID="grfStatus" runat="server" PaletteCustomColors="2, 65, 142; 255, 128, 0; Yellow; Red; Lime" Height="400px" Width="600px" BorderlineColor="Transparent">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes="True" AlignmentOrientation="All">
                <AxisY MaximumAutoSize="100">
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX MaximumAutoSize="100">
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Titles>
            <asp:Title Name="Title1" Text="Gráfico de Status" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 18pt" ForeColor="White">
            </asp:Title>
        </Titles>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Row" />
        </Legends>
        <BorderSkin BackColor="0, 65, 139" BorderColor="Transparent" SkinStyle="FrameTitle8" />
    </asp:Chart>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <asp:Chart ID="grfClientes" runat="server" PaletteCustomColors="2, 65, 142; 255, 128, 0; Yellow; Red; Lime" Height="400px" Width="600px">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="StackedBar" IsVisibleInLegend="False"></asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes="True" AlignmentOrientation="All">
                <AxisY MaximumAutoSize="100">
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX MaximumAutoSize="100">
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Titles>
            <asp:Title Name="Title1" Text="Gráfico de Evolução por Empresa" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 18pt" ForeColor="White">
            </asp:Title>
        </Titles>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Row" />
        </Legends>
        <BorderSkin BackColor="0, 65, 139" SkinStyle="FrameTitle8" />
    </asp:Chart>
</div>
```

C#

```
#region Populo o gráfico de pizza
grfStatus.Series.Clear();
//grfStatus.Legends.Clear();
//grfStatus.Legends.Add(nomeLegenda);
List<GraficoContagemStatus> relacaoStatus = visaoAgendamentoControle.ObterRelacaoGraficoContagemStatus(resultado);

grfStatus.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
grfStatus.Series.Add(new Series("Data"));
grfStatus.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
//grfStatus.Series["Data"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
//grfStatus.Series["Data"]["PieLineColor"] = "Black";
grfStatus.Series["Data"].Points.DataBindXY(relacaoStatus.Select(data => data.Status.ToString()).ToArray(),
                                           relacaoStatus.Select(data => data.Contagem).ToArray());
#endregion

#region Populo o gráfico de barras (duplas)
grfClientes.Series.Clear();
//grfClientes.Legends.Clear();
//grfClientes.Legends.Add(nomeLegenda);
List<GraficoContagemClienteUz> relacaoClientes = visaoAgendamentoControle.ObterRelacaoGraficoContagemClienteUz(resultado);

foreach (GraficoContagemClienteUz cliente in relacaoClientes)
{
    grfClientes.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
    grfClientes.Series.Add(new Series(cliente.CLIENTE));
    grfClientes.Series[cliente.CLIENTE].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

    List<GraficoContagemClienteUz> rel = relacaoClientes.Where(x => x.CLIENTE == cliente.CLIENTE).ToList();

    grfClientes.Series[cliente.CLIENTE].Points.DataBindXY(rel.Select(data => data.CLIENTE.ToString()).ToArray(),
                                                          rel.Select(data => data.QTD_UZ).ToArray());
}
#endregion
```

E segue a imagem do resultado de como está hoje:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema.
O que acontecia, é que dentro da minha estrutura de repetição, eu estava criando novos chartAreas e novas Series.
Modifiquei a estrutura de forma que o loop apenas popule as informações e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Se possível, adicionar como ficou se código. Essa resposta poderá ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema no futuro. xD